# Bind DisplayMemberPath to the ItemTemplate of the ListBox dynamically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a custom control that has an `ItemsSource` and `DisplayMemberPath` properties, and in the `ControlTemplate` there's a `ListBox` control that's bound to this `ItemsSourse`, I want to use the property specified by `DisplayMemberPath` in this ListBox, unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DisplayMemberPath}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
```

**EDIT**

As  Mike Strobel suggested in the comment and as I read in some blog posts, I removed the ItemTemplate and provided only the `DisplayMemberPath` in the ListBox but this doesn't even bint to the list (there's no scroll bar):

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}" 
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DisplayMemberPath}"/>
```

I even hard-coded the `DisplayMemberPath` value and still not working!, it's only working with `List<string>` not `List<CustomClass>`

**Solution**

Pardon, I missed changing the DP type from `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<object>`
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This would not work.  As written, you would be binding to the `DisplayMemberPath` property, i.e., the path itself, and not the value residing along path.  Are you even allowed to set _both_ `ItemTemplate` and `DisplayMemberPath`?  They’re supposed to be mutually exclusive: the latter is a simple substitute for the former.  It makes no sense to set both.  If you only need the path, just bind the display member path of the `ListBox` to the templated parent’s, just like you do for `ItemsSource`.  No need for an item template.

Comment: Please see the edit, I did what you're suggesting, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the TemplatedParent object isn't what you think it is?  Have you tried traversing back by specified type?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type **TYPE**}}, Path=DisplayMemberPath}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Ok, does the debug output give any clues when you run the application? "Property 'DisplayMemberPath' not found on object '???'" or some such?

Comment: The type of the object that has the DisplayMemberPath property. You're not showing how you're setting it, so it's impossible for me to know. Therefore the dummy type that you have to replace with the correct type.